# Generic BiDiMap

Tags: java, generics, hashmap, bidirectional

I have a BiDiMap class. How can I make it generic, by accepting not only `String` but also `Object` type of objects as input parameters, with keeping all the original functions working. For example I'd like to be able to use function `put()` with `Object`, `Object` as input parameters instead of `String`, `String`. I'd like to change all the input parameters and returning values of `String` type to `Object` types.

```
package MyBiDiMap;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class BiDiMap {

    private Map<String, String> keyValue;
    private Map<String, String> valueKey;

    public BiDiMap() {
        this.keyValue = new HashMap<>();
        this.valueKey = new HashMap<>();
    }

    private BiDiMap(Map<String, String> keyValue,
            Map<String, String> valueKey) {
        this.keyValue = keyValue;
        this.valueKey = valueKey;
    }

    public void put(String key, String value) {
        if (this.keyValue.containsKey(key)
                || this.valueKey.containsKey(value)) {
            this.remove(key);
            this.removeInverse(value);
        }
        this.keyValue.put(key, value);
        this.valueKey.put(value, key);
    }

    public String get(String key) {
        return this.keyValue.get(key);
    }

    public String getInverse(String value) {
        return this.valueKey.get(value);
    }

    public void remove(String key) {
        String value = this.keyValue.remove(key);
        this.valueKey.remove(value);
    }

    public void removeInverse(String value) {
        String key = this.valueKey.remove(value);
        this.keyValue.remove(key);
    }

    public int size() {
        return this.keyValue.size();
    }

    public BiDiMap getInverse() {
        return new BiDiMap(this.valueKey, this.keyValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Everywhere you have a string, replace it with a generic.

Comment: Thank you both of you. Never would have thought that it would be so simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple: by introducing two generic types, named K and V on your class and by then vigorously replacing all occurance of String with K (where your key type should be used), and similarly with V where values are required.

In other words: don't use specific types when declaring the two maps, but in all places, use the new generic types you added on class level.